# Magento-Go developer API

Tags: magento, magento-go

Anyone to help me with an info on the magento hosted ecommerce service [Magento-Go] API?
Seems very little info out there. thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you need to see the documentation?

It is located here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/go/support/api/.

It is pretty self explanatory.